# Is there a way I can make my code repeat this?

Tags: python, list

So I was given a variable n, and I had to find the value OF EACH DIGIT in the number, square them, and add it together. For example, if n = 145, so (1^2)+(4^2)+(5^2) = 42 and the same process repeats until one of the digits is either 1 or 4. How can I do that??

```
number = 145
sum_of_digits = 0
for digit in str(number):
    sum_of_digits += (int(digit)**2)
print(sum_of_digits)
```

This is my code so far.. It successfully squares and adds every single digit in the number but it doesn't repeat until either one of the digits is 1 or 4... so what am I supposed to do?

by the way, if the digit that came first is 1, the output should be false and i the digit is 4, the output should be true.

Comment: Either the result contains a 1 or a 4 or it does not, I don't understand what you mean by "repeat until either one of the digits is 1 or 4"

Comment: so like if for instance if n = 989, using my code it will only print (9^2) + (8^2)+(9^2), which is 226, but since there is no 1 or 4 in 226, I want it to loop around and print again and again if necessary until one of the digits in the numbers is either 1 or 4... so yea how can I do that??

Comment: why would there EVER be a 1 or 4 in the result if there wasn't one in the first loop?

Comment: Better if you put that explanation in the question

Comment: Yea, there isn't any, but if u repeat the process used in n = 989, for n = 226, as I mentioned earlier, so (2^2)+(2^2)+(6^2), which is 44, and 44 fits the requirements as it is digit 4... so how do I create a program that will repeat this process until at least one digit is either a 1 or a 4.

Comment: Why do anything to 145 then? It already has 1 and 4

Comment: yea 145 is just an example, I want to make sure that for other numbers such as 989, it will work as well

Comment: I understood what you want now. All you had to say was "apply the same logic to the result".

Comment: Please don't keep changing your Problem description (req.) while people has been helping you and post the answers...

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest your for-loop in a while-loop so that the process can repeat on the resulting number until it contains either a 1 or a 4.  You should process the intermediate results as strings to make this easier

```
number = 145
sum_of_digits = "" # intermediate results as strings

while not ('1' in sum_of_digits or '4' in sum_of_digits): # check for 1 or 4

    sum_of_digits = 0                    #
    for digit in str(number):            # your original loop
        sum_of_digits += (int(digit)**2) #

    number        = sum_of_digits        # new value for next loop
    sum_of_digits = str(sum_of_digits)   # intermediate results as strings 

print(sum_of_digits)

pos1   = sum_of_digits.find('1')           # position of '1' (or -1)
pos4   = sum_of_digits.find('4')           # position of '4' (or -1)
output = pos1<0 or pos4>=0 and pos4<pos1:  # 4 precedes 1 (or no 1)
```

You could also use the sum() function and a comprehension to compute the sum of digit squares:

```
n = 145
s = ""                                              # results as string
while set('14').isdisjoint(s):                      # loop until 1 or 4 found
    s = str(sum(d*d for d in map(int,s or str(n)))) # sum squares of digits
result = '4' in s.split('1')[0]                     # True if '4' before '1'

print(result) # True
```

This can be made into a recursive function:

```
def ssd(n,s=""):
    if set('14') & set(s): return '4' in s.split('1')[0]
    n = sum(d*d for d in map(int,s or str(n)))
    return ssd(n,str(n))
```

*Note that checking the input number before (or after) performing the first sum does make a difference in the result.  For example, 136 already contains a 1 so the function would return False if the input was checked immediately but it would return True if we only start checking after computing the sum of digit squares (136 --> 46).*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
number = 145
sum_of_digits = 0
while True:
    for digit in str(number):
       sum_of_digits += (int(digit)**2)
    if '1' in str(sum_of_digits):
      print('True')
    elif '4' in str(sum_of_digits):
      print('False')

print(sum_of_digits)
```

Comment: thank u very much, but I wanna add a little twist. What if like I want the code to print true if the number is 1 and false if the number is 4, how can I do that??

Comment: You could add this `New Requirement` into your Problem description.

Comment: I edited my code to adapt to your problem @Broski . Check if it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out it might help:

```
number = 145
sum_of_digits = 0
x = ''
while x not in ['1', '4']:
    for digit in str(number):
       sum_of_digits += (int(digit)**2)
    for i in str(sum_of_digits):
        if i == '1':
            print('False')
            x = '1'
        elif i == '4':
            print('True')
            x = '4'
print(sum_of_digits)
```